# Resetting HKWorkoutSession to zero

Tags: swift, watchkit, healthkit

My `saveWorkout()` function is called from an external ForceTouch `menuItem`. The `menuItem` calls its local `saveSession()` function which in turn calls that external `saveWorkout()` function. However When I start a new workout the session (run the app in Xcode), the workout continues where I left off. So if I ended my previous workout out at 2 mi 600 cal, the new workout starts from 2 mi 600 cal.

I end up having to delete all my Health app data and run the app again in order to start from zero.

Maybe I'm not understanding the functionality of HealthKit. When you `saveObject` where is the resetting of the workout being done?

p.s. When using a real watch even when I do delete all my data/app and start fresh the workout always starts at around the 5 mile mark. The sim starts at 0 if I delete all my data/app. Does this seem like a related issue?

WorkoutSessionManager.swift

```
func saveWorkout() {
    guard let startDate = self.workoutStartDate, endDate = self.workoutEndDate else {return}

    let workout = HKWorkout(activityType: self.workoutSession.activityType,
                            startDate: startDate,
                            endDate: endDate,
                            duration: endDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate),
                            totalEnergyBurned: self.currentActiveEnergyQuantity,
                            totalDistance: self.currentDistanceQuantity,
                            metadata: nil)

    var allSamples: [HKQuantitySample] = []
    allSamples += self.activeEnergySamples
    allSamples += self.distanceSamples
    allSamples += self.heartRateSamples

    self.healthStore.saveObject(workout) { (success, error) in

        if success && allSamples.count > 0 {
            self.healthStore.addSamples(allSamples, toWorkout: workout, completion: { (success, error) in

                print("Successful")
            })
        }else{
            print("Failed")
        }
    }        
}
```

DashboardViewController.swift

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
    WorkoutSessionManager.sharedManager?.delegate = self
    addMenuItemWithItemIcon(.Accept, title: "Save", action: #selector(DashboardController.saveSession))

    if context is WorkoutSessionContext {
        WorkoutSessionManager.sharedManager(context as! WorkoutSessionContext)
    } else {
        print("Fix")
    }
}

func saveSession() {
    WorkoutSessionManager.sharedManager!.saveWorkout()
}
```

Comment: I would like to completely cancel a workout. Any updates here?